# What's with the Bloodrager's underwhelming spell list?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, class

I noticed the Bloodrager spell list is unusually small, to the point of offering fewer spells than what the bloodrager is expected to learn through class levels. For example, the bloodrager is supposed to know 5 4th-level spells by 20th level, yet the Bloodrager spell list only lists *one* 4th-level spell. The Bloodrager's class entry only mentions them learning spells from the Bloodrager spell list.

Is there a misprint somewhere or some errata I missed? Where are the *rest* of the Bloodrager's spells?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't know why you think there's only one fourth level spell. [Here is the complete bloodrager spell list on d20PFSRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/spell-lists-and-domains/bloodrager), I count somewhere around 48 4th level spells.

Oh, I see - you are just looking at the list of net-new bloodrager spells in the back of the book. Go to the actual bloodrager class description on p.22 of the ACG. It includes both those new bloodrager-only spells but also the rest of their selection.

Comment: Ok yeah, that would explain a lot. Thanks for that.